# Is there a need for repeating rule parameters in iptables?

Tags: iptables

Let's say we need some ssh rules in iptables. But we also want to specify another chain for all the rules. We could use something like this:

```
iptables -t filter -N ssh
iptables -t filter -N tcp
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j tcp
iptables -t filter -A tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ssh
iptables -t filter -A ssh -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -s 10.10.10.10/32 -m mac --mac-source 10:10:10:10:10:10 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A ssh -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -s 11.11.11.11/32 -m mac --mac-source 11:11:11:11:11:11 -j ACCEPT
```

Do we have to specify all the options in each rule, or can this be omitted in lower chains? For instance, the final ssh rules could look like this:

```
iptables -t filter -A ssh -s 10.10.10.10/32 -m mac --mac-source 10:10:10:10:10:10 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A ssh -s 11.11.11.11/32 -m mac --mac-source 11:11:11:11:11:11 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid that then you need a new chain:

```
iptables -N sshgroup1
# or reset with iptables -F sshgroup1 if it already exists
iptables -t filter -A ssh -s 10.10.10.10/32 -m mac \
  --mac-source 10:10:10:10:10:10 -j sshgroup1
iptables -t filter -A sshgroup1 ... -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A sshgroup1 ... -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I don't get it -- to avoid what?

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov To avoid repeating the parameters. Isn't that what your question was about?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know if it's better to use the full-parameter rule in the case of separate chains because the example rules I gave, they work, and I'm wondering if repeating over and over the same parameters is kind of redundant because a packet that hits one chain goes through the rules of the chain, so using `--dport 22` again in the chain won't change anything. Am I right?

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov It's best to create custom chains `-N [custom chain]` and a single `-j [custom chain]` rule to match the packets and send them to the respective chains, such as in the answer.  This will save you from repeating the same options/parameters multiple times and if you give your chains meaningful names it helps with managing them in the future

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow ssh connections from only two hosts in your LAN then you should keep this rules on the top to have iptables work faster.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 10.10.10.10/32 -m mac --mac-source 10:10:10:10:10:10 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 11.11.11.11/32 -m mac --mac-source 11:11:11:11:11:11 -j ACCEPT
```

Otherwise there are a lot of combinations depending upon your network, policies and traffic.

The thumb rule is: Try to avoid repeating the rules, and minimize the level of matching for faster performance.